# Javascript cannot override window.confirm with async and promise

Tags: javascript

Everywhere in my project I have

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){
```

I need to override all with a more cute/nice dialog. 
I cannot change manually all the confirms, so I need to override the confirm. 
I made a simple test with **promise** and **async**, to see if it works

I have tried to override confirm like this:

```
window.confirm = async function(message){
```

but is not working(immediately returns true, instead of waiting 2 sec as it should in my sample)

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

// override confirm
window.confirm = async function(message){
        var result = await someAsyncFunc(); 

        return result;
}

// display a confirm
DisplayConfirm();

// delay the result 2sec
async function someAsyncFunc(){
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => res(true), 2000)
    });

    // wait until the promise returns us a value
    let result = await promise;    

    return result;
}

function DisplayConfirm(){
    if(confirm("it is a yes or a no ?")){
        alert("you clicked YES");
    }
    else{
        alert("you clicked NO");
    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

This sample should display a dialog, and after 2 sec to automatically return true.

You can try the code here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gk4b5uwp/



Please help

Comment: Does it have to be async?

Comment: Yes, because the dialog that will replace the confirm, will have to wait for user click('yes' or 'no')

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that what you are trying to do is not possible. When you make a function `async`, that function will run asynchronous. This means that when you call it, your currently running code will not wait for the function to finish, but instead it continues and the function you are calling will run at a later time. When you call your async function, it'll immediately returns a Promise, which is a truthy value so your `if` will always be executed.

If your function needs to wait until the Promise is resolved, you'll need to either use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator (only possible inside an `async` function) or use the [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) of the promise.

Either way, it is not possible to make the `confirm` async, without changing the places it is called from.

Below is an example of how you will need to change your `confirm` in order to make it asynchronous:

```js
window.confirm = async function() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

// Using .then()
confirm("it is a yes or a no ?").then(function(outcome) {
  if (outcome) {
    console.log("you clicked YES");
  } else {
    console.log("you clicked NO");
  }
});

// Using await
(async function () {
  if (await confirm("it is a yes or a no ?")) {
    console.log("you clicked YES");
  } else {
    console.log("you clicked NO");
  }
})();
```

But since you need to change the calls to `confirm` anyway, I'd recommend not overriding the native `confirm()`, but to name it differently and call that function instead. This can prevent some odd behavior. For instance, when a library calls the `confirm()`.